# Referring css files in Spring project

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm referring my resources in my Spring project as below

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

jsp files

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" />"></script>
        <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/startpage.js" />"></script>
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/startpage.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now, I have a "image" folder within the resources folder and I want to refer few images in my css files.

How can I refer that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put `img` tag to your .jsp file

```
<img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/image/picture1.png" alt="" title="" />
```

edit1. In the css file

```
#yourcssclass {
width: 46px;
height: 44px;
background: url(/resources/image/picture1.png) 0 0;
}
```

Comment: I need to add it to the css file and not in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Its all about relativity.

Lets say your resource folder is broken down into:
-image
-js
-css

If you have file in css test.css you wish to edit to include image from image folder, you need to do something like following.

```
#testdiv {
background-image: url('../image/testimage.jpg')
}
```

Comment: Yep, i use it on linux and windows machines. Works fine for me.